# Material-UI DataGrid Column Filter doesn't work with Material-UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I have the following problem: I have made a Material-UI DataGrid in React JS which I would like to use inside a Material-UI DialogContent. Everything in the table works correctly when put in a Dialog - ordering, renderCells, checkboxSelection, etc. except for using the default filtering. Here is a bare bones example which recreates the bug: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-stallman-sev7x?file=/src/demo.js

Clicking on the column name/options then clicking on "filter" brings out the bug, which is that you can't type in the filter field. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Thanks in advance and sorry if question is phrased badly or a duplicate, first post here on SO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add disableEnforceFocus to the Dialog component.

```
  <Dialog disableEnforceFocus fullWidth maxWidth="xl" open={true} onClose={this.onClose}>
    <DialogTitle>Test Dialog Grid</DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent>t>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
        <DataGrid columns={columns} rows={rows} autoHeight />;
      </div>
    </DialogContent>
  </Dialog>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
        <DataGrid columns={columns} rows={rows} autoHeight />;
      </div>
  </div>
```