# Cannot enter any value on Filter Value Datagrid Material-UI in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

There is a problem that in Material-UI DataGrid, I cannot enter or edit any value on filter value like below picture. Actually, it seems that the Filter value editable is disabled.
It would be grateful if you help me to solve the problem. Tnx
[image]

The source code of it is:

```
         let columns = [


            { field: 'sensortype', headerName: 'SensorType', width: 140, hide: columnfilter.hidehabibsensortype },
            { field: 'height', headerName: 'Longitude', width: 130, hide: columnfilter.hidelongitude },
            { field: 'width', headerName: 'Latitude', width: 130, hide: columnfilter.hidelatitude },
            { field: 'altitude', headerName: 'Altitude', width: 130, hide: columnfilter.hidealtitude },
            { field: 'distance', headerName: 'Distance', width: 130, hide: columnfilter.hidedistance },
            { field: 'speed', headerName: 'Speed', width: 130, hide: columnfilter.hidespeed },
            { field: 'callsign', headerName: 'CallSign', width: 130, hide: columnfilter.hidecallsign },
            { field: 'squawk', headerName: 'Squawk', width: 130, hide: columnfilter.hidesquawk },
            { field: 'country', headerName: 'Country', width: 130, hide: columnfilter.hidecountry },

        ];

            logs && logs.length && logs.map((log, index) => (

               let row = {
                    id: index,
                    sensortype: log && log[0] && log[0].sensorTypeLatinName ? log[0].sensorTypeLatinName : '0',
                    height: log && log[0] && log[0].longitude ? log[0].longitude : '0',
                    width: log && log[0] && log[0].latitude ? log[0].latitude : '0',
                    altitude: log && log[0] && log[0].altitude ? log[0].altitude : '0',
                    distance: log && log[0] && log[0].distance ? log[0].distance : '0',
                    speed: log && log[0] && log[0].speed ? log[0].speed : '0',
                    squawk: log && log[0] && log[0].squawk ? log[0].squawk : '0',
                    callsign: log && log[0] && log[0].callsign ? log[0].callsign : '0',
                    country: log && log[0] && log[0].country ? log[0].country : '0',

                },

                rowss.push(row)

            ))

                            <div style={{ height: 230, width: '100%', direction: "rtl", }} className={classes.root}>
                                <DataGrid rows={rowss} columns={columns} components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}

                                    pageSize={100} hideFooter hideFooterPagination density="compact" />
                            </div>
```

Comment: Please reproduce your example on codesandbox.

Comment: This might do the trick, I had the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67221608/10755540

Answer (score 1):

Add `disableEnforceFocus` to the `Dialog` component:

```
<Dialog disableEnforceFocus fullWidth maxWidth="xl" open={true} onClose={this.onClose}>
  <DialogTitle>Test Dialog Grid</DialogTitle>
  <DialogContent>
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
      <DataGrid columns={columns} rows={rows} autoHeight />;
    </div>
  </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.